# Script in index.html interferes with Http redirects

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, https, stripe-payments

I have function HttpsRedirect that wraps around my app, which works fine. However, I integrated stripe into my site, which requires loading the script `<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>` in the index.html. When I run the app in production through http:// i get this error `Live Stripe.js integrations must use HTTPS` and the app crashes.

```
const HttpsRedirect = ({ disabled, children }) => {
  if (
    !disabled &&
    typeof window !== "undefined" &&
    window.location &&
    window.location.protocol === "http:" &&
    !isLocalHost(window.location.hostname)
  ) {
    window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(/^http(?!s)/, "https");
    return null;
  }

  return children;
};
```

```
<HttpRedirect>
   <App />
</HttpRedirect>
```

Is there any way to redirect to https first before the script loads? I tried looking into forcing redirect to https through heroku and node, but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Load the script programticly(see here:https://usehooks.com/useScript/ ) after you redirect to `https`

Comment: On the stripe site they recommend that the script be loaded onto every page: 
"Include the Stripe.js script on each page of your site—it should always be loaded directly from https://js.stripe.com, rather than included in a bundle or hosted yourself.

To best leverage Stripe’s advanced fraud functionality, include this script on every page, not just the checkout page. This allows Stripe to detect anomalous behavior that may be indicative of fraud as customers browse your website."